# NullPointerException thrown by Apache Wink Accept in WAS Liberty 8.5.5.1

Tags: apache-wink, websphere-liberty

NullPointerException in Apache Wink. I've read it maybe jar conflicts but I don't see anything bundled in my war that conflicts. 
Any WAS liberty logs I can turn on that can provide more details?

```
[04/12/13 16:58:26:978 GMT] 00000026 org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor             E An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf(Accept.java:139)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptHeader(HttpHeadersImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptableMediaTypes(HttpHeadersImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterByProduces(ResourceRegistry.java:573)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterDispatchMethods(ResourceRegistry.java:497)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.findMethod(ResourceRegistry.java:359)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodWADLHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodWADLHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1060)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4510)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

[04/12/13 16:58:27:009 GMT] 00000026 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.ApplicationErrorUtils           E SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf:139'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf(Accept.java:139)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptHeader(HttpHeadersImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptableMediaTypes(HttpHeadersImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterByProduces(ResourceRegistry.java:573)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterDispatchMethods(ResourceRegistry.java:497)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.findMethod(ResourceRegistry.java:359)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodWADLHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodWADLHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1060)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4510)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

[04/12/13 16:58:27:197 GMT] 00000026 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters 1105" at ffdc_13.12.04_16.58.27.0.log
[04/12/13 16:58:27:212 GMT] 00000026 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:153)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1145)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4510)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf(Accept.java:139)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptHeader(HttpHeadersImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptableMediaTypes(HttpHeadersImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterByProduces(ResourceRegistry.java:573)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterDispatchMethods(ResourceRegistry.java:497)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.findMethod(ResourceRegistry.java:359)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodWADLHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodWADLHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1060)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf:139'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836129/srve0777e-exception-thrown-by-application-class-org-apache-wink-common-interna)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case swagger was pulling in dependencies that caused my problem